# Flutter video player using high data

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-video-player

When i use flutter normal video player in my project when video playing high data consumption and data using speed above internet speed indicator show above 3 to 5 MB speed ,

how decease data consumption and how limit data speed

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a lower resolution video: Lower resolution videos will have a smaller file size, which will result in less data being used.

se a video streaming service: Instead of downloading the entire video, a streaming service will only download the parts of the video that are currently being watched, which can decrease data usage.

also you can use Limit data speed: You can limit the data speed in your app by using a package like "data_usage" or you can use "flutter_speedometer" package to show the internet speed in your app.